# seeded data is duplicated code first migration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-migrations

I have seeded the database using code first migration, however I noticed when I view the seeded data in index.html, the data is replicated.

This is the configuration file were I seeded the data:

internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

```
    protected override void Seed(OnlineBookStore.Models.OnlineBookStoreDB context)
    {

        var books = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Book>
        {
            new Book {

        BookStatus = new BookStatus { Status = "New" },
            Genre = new Genre { Name = "Thriller" },
            Author = new Author { Name = "Paula Hawkins" },
            Title = "The Girl On The Train",
            Description = "Rachel catches the same commuter train            morning. ",
           ISBN = 0552779776,

            },


        new Book
        {
            BookStatus = new BookStatus { Status = "Best Seller" },
            Genre = new Genre { Name = "Childrens" },
            Author = new Author { Name = "Roald Dahl" },
            Title = "The Witches",
            Description = "Beware. Real witches dress in ordinary clothes",


            ISBN = 0141365471,

        },
         },

       };

 books.ForEach(s =>context.Books.AddOrUpdate(p => new { p.ISBN, p.Title } ));
          context.SaveChanges();


    }
}
```

}

I am really unsure of were I am going wrong, spent days on this!
Really appreciate anyones help! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the key in AddOrUpdate to prevent duplicates since Seed() runs with every update-database issued.

```
// build your books collection
    var books = new []
    {
        new Book {

    BookStatus = new BookStatus { Status = "New" },
        Genre = new Genre { Name = "Thriller" },
        Author = new Author { Name = "Paula Hawkins" },
        Title = "The Girl On The Train",
        Description = "Rachel catches the same commuter train            morning. ",
       ISBN = 0552779776,

        },


    new Book
    {
        BookStatus = new BookStatus { Status = "Best Seller" },
        Genre = new Genre { Name = "Childrens" },
        Author = new Author { Name = "Roald Dahl" },
        Title = "The Witches",
        Description = "Beware. Real witches dress in ordinary clothes",


        ISBN = 0141365471,

    },
     },

   };    


context.Books.AddOrUpdate(p => new { p.ISBN, p.Title }, books);
context.SaveChanges();
```

See http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/take-care-with-ef-4-3-addorupdate-method/

Comment: thanks, I did that but it states that p does not exist in the current context, the p in the following code is were I think the error is as it is (the p) highlighted red: new { p.ISBN, p.Title }

Comment: Sorry, mindlessly copied the code. You don't need a foreach if you've already built a collection. See edit.

Comment: thanks, tried your code it did not work, the books in the following code appears as error, context.Books.AddOrUpdate(p => new { p.ISBN, p.Title }, books);

Comment: What's the error? Try changing List to array. See edit.

Comment: so what happens is that everytime I update the database, the seeded data/the book details are added to the database and the old data is not removed.So I end up having repeated data

Comment: Did you start clean with no data and the revised code? I use this type of thing in numerous apps. Another approach is to enclose the code in something like if (!context.Books.Any(b => b.ISBN == "0552779776") { ... }